# Overlaying Div on Image Not Working in Bootstrap 5 Card Body

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm creating an application that allows the user to design an item by inputting text which will then be generated on the item and displayed as a preview image.

I have the `<img>` being displayed in a Bootstrap 5 card with a header. I want to add a loading overlay to the image that can be shown by adjusting `display` when a new image is being generated.

I mostly understand that I can use `position-relative` and `position-absolute` to achieve something like this and that's exactly what [this answer I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68710183/17111223) does, however, it doesn't seem to work when I try to do it in the body of the card, not the entire card (as I don't want that, just the image to have the overlay).

Here's what happens when I try to do it in the card body:

https://codepen.io/jj15asmr/pen/poqKqej

```html
<div class="container my-3">
    <div class="card rounded-0 shadow-sm">
        <div class="card-header">
            Preview
        </div>
        <div class="card-body my-3">
            <div class="position-relative">
                <img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://placehold.co/2000x400" alt="Generated item preview">
                
                <div class="position-absolute w-100 h-100">
                <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the positioning doesn't seem to have any effect as the image can still be right-clicked (meaning it's not overlayed):

And here's when I try to do it with the entire card:

https://codepen.io/jj15asmr/pen/ZEVRVoe

```html
<div class="container my-3">
    <div class="card rounded-0 shadow-sm position-relative">
        <div class="card-header">
            Preview
        </div>
        <div class="card-body my-3">
                <img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://placehold.co/2000x400" alt="Generated item preview">
    </div>
        
    <div class="position-absolute w-100 h-100">
                <div class="spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
        </div>
</div>
```

The positioning does work because I can't right-click the image anymore.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into the question, please do not just send us to external platforms.

Comment: You have not specified _where_ you want the element to be positioned absolute. If you leave all four of `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` at their default value `auto` - then the element will be position absolute in the exact same place it would start at in normal flow. You need to set at least `top: 0;` here.

Comment: @CBroe Ah, okay. That makes sense now and is now looking closer to what I want. Thank you and apologies for not adding an example directly to the question, will keep it in mind for the future.